# Service Worker not registering on gh-pages hosted website

Tags: javascript, https, github-pages, service-worker, offline-caching

The service worker is registered and works fine on the vscode localhost but not on the gh-pages hosted site.

Screenshot of localhost sw.

[image: screenshot of localhhost sw]

[image: screenshot of gh-pages sw]

As you can see the sw opens the cache but then fails to register with a type error in promise. While sometimes the sw not even opens the cache and fails.

Below is my snippet to install and update the service worker.

```js
var CACHE_NAME = 'dev';
var urlsToCache = [
  '/',
  '/styles/style.css',
];


// Installing a sevice worker and defining files to be cached. 
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  // Perform install steps
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
      .then(function(cache) {
        console.log('Opened cache');
        return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
      })
  );
});


// Updating the service worker.
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    event.respondWith(
      caches.match(event.request)
        .then(function(response) {
          // Cache hit - return response
          if (response) {
            return response;
          }
  
          // IMPORTANT: Clone the request. A request is a stream and
          // can only be consumed once. Since we are consuming this
          // once by cache and once by the browser for fetch, we need
          // to clone the response.
          var fetchRequest = event.request.clone();
  
          return fetch(fetchRequest).then(
            function(response) {
              // Check if we received a valid response
              if(!response || response.status !== 200 || response.type !== 'basic') {
                return response;
              }
  
              // IMPORTANT: Clone the response. A response is a stream
              // and because we want the browser to consume the response
              // as well as the cache consuming the response, we need
              // to clone it so we have two streams.
              var responseToCache = response.clone();
  
              caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
                .then(function(cache) {
                  cache.put(event.request, responseToCache);
                });
  
              return response;
            }
          );
        })
      );
  });


Below is my snippet to register the service worker.
```

```html
 <!-- Service worker -->
    <script>
        if('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
          navigator.serviceWorker
                .register('sw.js')
                .then(function() { console.log("Service Worker Registered"); });
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your

```
var urlsToCache = [
  '/',
  '/styles/style.css',
];
```

doesn't correspond to the actual URLs that you intend to cache when you're in the GitHub Pages environment.

Instead of absolute URLs that start with `/`, you should use relative URLs, since all your resources are under a subdirectory of your GitHub Pages' root.

```
var urlsToCache = [
  './',
  './styles/style.css',
];
```

Should work in both `localhost` and in your GitHub Pages environments.

Comment: Actually I have shifted to heroku and now the sw works fine. Although there's some issues. When I deploy a new build and revisit the site in the browser the sw fetches the new build but that is not the case with the home screen added app that fires as standalone. For it to be updated too I've to manually clear the site's cache from the browser. Is there nay way I can make the sw fetch the new builds from home screen too?

Comment: I'll also try your suggestion for the gh-pages.